# Can't find a itunes App in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I wanted to install some App off of the iTunes to see how it will work before putting down money to buy an iPad. But, I couldn't find any iTunes in the iPad simulator! I am totally a newbie. Could someone show me the way? Is this by design?

Thanks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Simulator is for testing your own Apps not third Party apps from other developers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is by design. The only built-in apps that come with the simulator are:

- Safari
- Photos
- Contacts
- Game Center
- Newsstand
- Settings